# Why "delete" can be used here?

Tags: c++, pointers

Since delete is used to free memory that's dynamically allocated by new, why delete can be used in the following code?

This coding comes from "Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in Cpp 2014" figure 4.27

```
void makeEmpty( BinaryNode*& t)
{
    if(t!=nullptr)
    {
        makeEmpty(t->left);
        makeEmpty(t->right);
        delete t;
    }
    t=nullptr;
}
```

Problem solved, all the BinaryNodes are created by new either created or copied from other BinaryTrees. Thus it will be appropriate to use delete here.

Comment: ***Why “delete” can be used here?*** Because the left and right trees have been freed already when `delete t;` is called.

Comment: Any reason you think it can not be called here? I am trying to understand your concern.

Comment: @drescherjmCause I think it's "delete" that free the left and right trees as well as t.

Comment: Deleting a node won't free the child subtrees unless the node destructor frees them or you're using smart pointers.

Comment: It could do that, but nodes aren't always the best place to make decisions about the tree.

Answer (score 0):

The caller is expected to pass in a reference to a `BinaryNode*` that points to an object allocated with `new`. Thus it is safe to pass it to `delete`.

```
BinaryNode *j = new BinaryNode (...);
// more code
makeEmpty (j);
// j will now be nullptr
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why “delete” can be used here?

The program is well-formed because `t` is an object pointer, and thus of a valid type for an argument of `delete`.

If `t` is valid and points to an object allocated with `new` and the dynamic type of the object is appropriate, then the behaviour is well-defined.